# Magento 2 How to hide "Sub Total" div in mini cart if not items in cart?

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

In Magento 2.3.5-p1 I want to hide the **"Sub Total"** div if no items in the cart. Also, if the cart has items then that div will show again. How can I achieve this?

There is a "subtotal.html" file in "web/template/minicart/item/" the file content as below:

```
<div class="subtotal">
    <span class="label">
        <!-- ko i18n: 'Cart Subtotal' --><!-- /ko -->
    </span>

    <!-- ko foreach: elems -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

As this div is updating with a knockout Js, can we place any custom class to that div or any other way? please suggest the quickest solution.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the store URL? so I will check and give you one line CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code should be coming from .html file. You can set the condition like

```
  <!-- ko if: cart().subtotal -->
    <span data-bind="html: cart().subtotal" class="counter"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: cart().subtotal -->
    <span data-bind="html: 0" class="counter">0</span>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it in subtotal.html but it is always showing counter 0. if the cart has items or not.

Comment: is there override the block or js???

Comment: Its HTML file which is "app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/subtotl.html"